# how to express this JSON to a C# class

Tags: c#, json

How can I express the following JSON to a C# class? The item numbers (oi_abc, oi_def) will always be unique values I have to pass into the POST.

```
{
  "availabilities": {
    "oi_abc": {
      "available_quantity": 0,
      "discontinued": true
    },
    "oi_def": {
      "available_quantity": 4,
      "discontinued": false,
      "backordered_until": "2019-03-15T00:10:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a dictionary for `availabilities`?

Something like:

```
public class Model {
    public Dictionary<string, AvailabilityInfo> availabilities { get; set; }
}

public class AvailabilityInfo {
    public int available_quantity { get; set; }
    public boolean discontinued { get; set; }
    public DateTime? backordered_until { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, but a few of the property names would need the jsonproperty attribute. If not I believe it wouldn't be able to deserialize correctly.

Comment: That's why I said "something like" there are certainly going to need to be some type of mapping. It really would depend upon what OP decides to deserialise the JSON with.

Comment: Updated property names to match JSON.

Answer (score 1):

better to use c#  standarts of naming

```
   public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("availabilities")]
        public Dictionary<string,Availability>  Availabilities { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class Availability
    {
        [JsonProperty("available_quantity")]
        public long AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discontinued")]
        public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("backordered_until")]
        public DateTimeOffset BackorderedUntil { get; set; }
    }
```

and code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

but in some cases it is easier to use list instead of dictionary, so I would recommend this code

```
var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(json); 

List<Availability> availabilities = ((JObject)jsonParsed["availabilities"]).Properties()
                         .Select(x => new Availability { 
                         Name = x.Name, Available = x.Value.ToObject<Available>()
                         }).ToList().Dump();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Name": "oi_abc",
    "Available": {
      "AvailableQuantity": 0,
      "Discontinued": true,
      "BackorderedUntil": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "oi_def",
    "Available": {
      "AvailableQuantity": 0,
      "Discontinued": false,
      "BackorderedUntil": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

classes

```
public partial class Availability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Available Available { get; set; }
}

public partial class Available
{
    public long AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset BackorderedUntil { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass this json as a object. To that, create a classes like below. Otherwise send as json string and deserialize in c# method

```
public class availabilities
{
  public oiabc oi_abc {get;set;}
}

public class oiabc
{
  public int available_quantity {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I think the problem OP is trying to solve is that the properties `oi_abc` and `oi_def` will always be different.

Comment: Also, `oi-abc` is not valid! perhaps you meant `oi_abc`